# Is Interpretivism Opposed to Using Mathematics in Understanding Social Reality?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, positivism

Interpretivism rejects the the Positivist claim that social reality can be studied objectively the way we study physical occurrences. In addition, positivists believe that we can use mathematics to construct a formal model or explanation of a social phenomena. If Interpretivism rejects the objective analysis of social reality, does it mean that it also rejects the use mathematics in doing research?

Comment: I'd take Strong Claim of positivism as straight-forwardly wrong, as it has been pointed out; but the Weak Claim is possible, and sometimes advisable and other times neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Statistics, a form of mathematics, is a key tool for sociologists.  Standard deviations, mean, averages, remember the "Bell Curve" controversy?

Comment: Hi, In what 'sense' does statistics (or mathematics) corresponds to reality?